# itemize - alignment of custom bullet symbols

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists, itemize, fontawesome

I'm trying to use some icons from the `fontawesome` package as bullets for the `itemize` environment. As there are different characters and they are not the same width, the alignment looks mangled:

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0]
  \item[\faCode] Ruby, Python, Java, Javascript, Racket
  \item[\faGlobe] Sinatra, Rails, Django, Flask
  \item[\faHTMLfive] HTML5, CSS3, JQuery
  \item[\faCloud] Redis, CouchDB, PostgreSQL, MySQL
  \item[\faExchange] JSON, XML, OAuth
  \item[\faCodeFork] git, SVN
\end{itemize}
```

[image: Example itemize]

How can I align those symbols centred?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A variant using `\clap` from `mathtools` and the `wide`option of `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} \usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
% page 3 of manual
\SetLabelAlign{center}{\clap{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[wide, labelsep = 1em, align=center]
  \item[\faCode] Ruby, Python, Java, Javascript, Racket
  \item[\faGlobe] Sinatra, Rails, Django, Flask
  \item[\faHTMLfive] HTML5, CSS3, JQuery
  \item[\faCloud] Redis, CouchDB, PostgreSQL, MySQL
  \item[\faExchange] JSON, XML, OAuth
  \item[\faCodeFork] git, SVN
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\clap` = `\makebox[0pt]`

Comment: It's shorter to write :o)

Comment: @Werner Perhaps it will get used in a later answer?!

Comment: @Werner: I do not add loading `mathtools`: it replaces loading `amsmath`. But you're not quite wrong: I do add two characters.  However note I use `clap` more often than I load mathtools in a document…

Comment: Can this be made to work with Beamer? When I use `\setlist[itemize,1]{wide,labelsep=1em,align=center}` and `\SetLabelAlign{center}{\clap{#1}}
`, default itemize bullets become invisible and alignment is also incorrect.  EDIT: nevermind, already covered in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280568/itemize-in-beamer-alignment-of-custom-bullets .

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using `enumitem`, you can use `\SetLabelAlign` to define a center alignment; I also increased the valur for `leftmargin`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\SetLabelAlign{center}{\hss#1\hss}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=30pt,align=center]
  \item[\faCode] Ruby, Python, Java, Javascript, Racket
  \item[\faGlobe] Sinatra, Rails, Django, Flask
  \item[\faHTMLfive] HTML5, CSS3, JQuery
  \item[\faCloud] Redis, CouchDB, PostgreSQL, MySQL
  \item[\faExchange] JSON, XML, OAuth
  \item[\faCodeFork] git, SVN
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: any idea how to do this in `beamer`? The `enumitem` package doesn't seem to work so easily there...

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this, which is based on the definition of the `parleft` alignment provided by `enumitem`. Gonzalo Medina's answer is better but I'd already written this....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{enumitem}
% page 3 of manual
\SetLabelAlign{center}{\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\centering#1}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt,align=center]
  \item[\faCode] Ruby, Python, Java, Javascript, Racket
  \item[\faGlobe] Sinatra, Rails, Django, Flask
  \item[\faHTMLfive] HTML5, CSS3, JQuery
  \item[\faCloud] Redis, CouchDB, PostgreSQL, MySQL
  \item[\faExchange] JSON, XML, OAuth
  \item[\faCodeFork] git, SVN
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: centred labels]