# itemize in beamer - alignment of custom bullets

Tags: beamer, itemize, enumitem

I'm doing a `beamer` presentation and defined some custom `itemize` bullets, which look like this:

```
\newcommand{\pro}{\item[\textbf{\color{green}+}]}
\newcommand{\con}{\item[\hspace{-2ex}\textbf{\color{red}--}]}
```

They work very well, but are not centered under eachother, the `\con` sign is more indented than the `\pro` sign.

I tried

```
\begin{itemize}[align=center]
```

with no effect.

Is there a way without using `enumitem` (which isn't quite compatible to `beamer`) to align the customized bullets in a centered position?

Maybe it's also possible with `enumitem` and I haven't found the right way to implement it yet?

Comment: the bullet points are right aligned by default, so your `\hspace` is on the wrong side. Try something like `\newcommand{\con}{\item[\textbf{\color{red}--}\hspace{0.05cm}]}`

Comment: Thanks, that did work. But is there maybe a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have what you want with `mathtools` and its `\(math)clap` command.

I defined  differently your custom bullets, in math mode. Note the `endash` has not the same width as the `+` character.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand{\pro}{\item[\boldmath$\mathclap{\color{green}+}$ ]}
\newcommand{\con}{\item[\boldmath$ \mathclap{\color{red}-}$ ]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \pro item1 
    \con item2
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

*Note:* If the symbols that you want to use all have the same width, the `mathclap` command is not necessary.

[image]

Comment: Is `\mathclap` necessary? In math mode plus and minus have the same width in most fonts.

Comment: It was just in case. Actually, I initially retained the endash and  it then was necessary. Furthermore, I'm not sure, these are the only symbols the O?P. wants to use. I'll add some explanations about this.

Comment: The `$\boldmath$` solution didn't come to my mind, that one does the job very well! :) And as @egreg said, if you only use + and -, you won't need the `\mathclap`. But for further use, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Can this be generalized somehow so that mixing `\item` with `\item[\customSymbol]` works correctly? Default bullets are right-aligned (as if in `\llap`) and wider custom symbols stick out on the left.

Comment: @eudoxos: It seems that with `beamer` and just the above code, everything is centred (I've just tested with a custom  `++` label). Could you post a minimal example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: @Bernard: Can't add images to comments: http://i.imgur.com/aQQdnhN.png . The example wide symbol is `\StopWatchEnd` from `ifsym` package used first with `\item[\StopWatchEnd]` and second with `\item[\clap{\StopWatchEnd}]`. `\clap` centers around the tip of arrow-shaped default bullets and the symbol then sticks out to the right (I wrote left before, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

Since the `+` is larger than `--`, I centered the `--` in the same space.  This was complicated by the fact that `--` is slightly assymetrical as demonstrated in the `\fbox` demos, and of course `beamer` redefining everything.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newlength{\tempdima}

\newcommand{\pro}{\item[\color{green}\textbf{+}]}
\newcommand{\con}{\item[\settowidth{\tempdima}{\textbf{+}}%
  \hbox to \tempdima{\hfill\hspace{.07ex}\color{red}\textbf{--}\hfill}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \pro item1
    \con item2
  \end{itemize}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\textbf{--}}
{\Huge\fbox{\hspace{.07ex}\textbf{--}}}
{\tiny\fbox{\hspace{.07ex}\textbf{--}}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: + and --]