# Changing the bullet list symbol in beamer when used from pandoc

Tags: beamer, pandoc

I am new to `beamer` . I am looking for a traditional circular bullet instead of the sideways triangle: is this possible given I am using `pandoc` preamble?  It seems like none of the document level  LaTeX directives can be used when `pandoc` is employed.

```
---
title: Tensorflow
documentclass: beamer
colortheme: boadilla
fonttheme: structurebold
header-includes:
  - \setsansfont{Roboto}
  - \setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
output:
    highlight: tango
  rmarkdown::html_document:
    theme: lumen
    fig_caption: yes        
---
```

This is being run by

```
  pandoc -s -t beamer --toc-depth=5 --toc  --pdf-engine xelatex -o paper2.pdf p2.md
```

[image]

**Update** I added the `header-includes` with 2 `beamer` directives: however it had no effect.

Comment: `boadilla` is a theme, not a colour theme.

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280568/itemize-in-beamer-alignment-of-custom-bullets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX code in your example is not correctly escaped, if you put it in the YAML block. You can fix that by creating a new file, which contains all the code, you want to add to the preamble and call pandoc with `-H filename`.

test.md

```
---
title: Test
documentclass: beamer
---


- One
    - One and a half
- Two
```

header.incl

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]
```

Call pandoc:

```
$ pandoc test.md -H header.incl --pdf-engine=xelatex  -o test.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to maintain in one file?  It is far less manageable to separate out into headers: